# Проблема с иконкой

Tags: css, html5

Я уже битый час не могу понять, что с этим кодом не так! Иконка не устанавливается,  Путь перепроверил всеми возможными и невозможными способами. Что не так?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: При работе локально думаю правильнее будет не  указывать  абсолютный путь, попробуйте href="../CSS/css1.css" если конечно у вас файл находится в HTML/index.html

Comment: Основная причина не отображения или не обновления фавиконки это ее кеширование браузером. Используйте относительные пути, и возьмите за правило не использовать больше кириллические кракозябры в путях

Answer (score 2):

Ошибка в пути к файлам, а именно:

```
"C:\Users\user\Desktop\Женя\Sublime text\Сайт\СSS\css1.css"
```

Это неправильный путь, такие слеши используются в винде, вам же надо использовать такой

```
"C:/Users/user/Desktop/Женя/Sublime text/Сайт/СSS/css1.css"
```

А еще лучше сделать пути относительными:

```
/Сайт/СSS/css1.css
```

Про абсолютные и относительные пути можно почитать здесь 
http://htmlbook.ru/samhtml/ssylki/absolyutnye-i-otnositelnye-ssylki

Comment: Проблема не в CSS а в иконке, а проблему с CSS уже решил(с иконкой попробовал ваш совет, не получилось)

Comment: @ЖеняТарелин убери type="image/x-icon"

Comment: Убрал, не помогло

Comment: @ЖеняТарелин а Вы используете какой-то локальный сервер?

Comment: Нет, просто практикуюсь сам для себя

Comment: @ЖеняТарелин Есть подозрение что проблема в кириллице(название папки "Сайт")

Answer (score 0):

По пробуйте так --

```
<link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico?v=1.1">
```

либо так:

```
<link rel="icon" href="_/img/favicon.png">
```

Сейчас лучше использовать PNG. С разришением - 250x250 пойдет